# Pressing Back button to finish a series of Activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Suppose there is a button on the homepage of my Activity.

When I press this button, it goes to Activity A

in Activity A , it automatically goes to Activity B using Intents and startActivityForResult();

in Activity B , it automatically goes to Activity C using Intents and startActivityForResul();

in Activity B, it automatically starts the intent to go BarCode scanner activity and get results.

My problem is when I press a button to return to my home page, it requires pressing 4 times go back to my homepage

If I want to press back to my homepage at one time, how to finish such series of activities?

Comment: The back button is [supposed to work this way](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15939/android-back-button-global-history-back-or-menu-back). You probably want to implement the Up button (Honeycomb and later, unless you use something like ActionBarSherlock) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't Use/override onBackPressed() anywhere in your program

just add the following method in the parent activity such as Activity A and B

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Start Activity on your onClick method using

```
    startActivityForResult(intentName, 0);
```

In Child Activity you use/override onStop() method

```
    @Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();

}
```

Comment: I can not understand what you did here? Could you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

You can override the following method to return to homepage

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Within that method create the intent for home activity with the following tag

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

The document says

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.

But what i am wondering is, then why you are starting the activity for result, since you are not going to return to previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
finishActivity(requestCode)
```

use above code in last activity so that after pressing back button it will close all the activity that are started

requestcode is a code which you used in first activity to start activity B

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, otherActivity.class); // instead of otherActivity use your  activity
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
    startActivity(intent);
```

And, in your other onCreate() use below code -

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
    finish();
}
```